# Bootstrap Datatables: Change cell color based on values

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am getting json data from server and trying to display the datatable.

Code :

```
    var siteName = $("#stateType").val();

    $(".jqueryDataTable").DataTable({
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing" : false,
        "bServerSide" : false,
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "searchState",
        "sServerMethod" : "POST",
        "fnServerParams" : function(aoData) {
            aoData.push({
                "name" : "stateType",
                "value" : siteName
            });
        },
        "aoColumns" : [ {
            "mData" : "stitcher"
        }, {
            "mData" : "state"
        }, {
            "mData" : "load"
        }, {
            "mData" : "sessionsActive"
        }, {
            "mData" : "sessionsPaused"
        }, {
            "mData" : "csmVersion"
        }, {
            "mData" : "serviceID"
        } ]
    });
```

I am able to display the data. but the requirement is I need to change the color of the state cell based on value?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask a question. It is expected that you at least try, then if you have issues, we can help

Comment: Check this thread:-[Cell background color based on cell content](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11469/cell-background-color-based-on-cell-content)  And example link given in thread:- [Row created callback](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html)

Comment: Thanks or the quick response. Inside your link example the data is static but here I am fetching the data from server.

Comment: If you want an explicit answer then you'll have to tell us _exactly_ what you want - which cell? based on which value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below. Based on [columns.createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell)

```
{
   data: 'serviceID',
   createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    var serviceID = cellData;
                    if (serviceID < 1) {
                        $(td).css('color', 'red')
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: I am totally new in this. Can you please explain in my code.

Comment: I tried this one and it works.  Thank You                                                             "fnRowCallback": function ( nRow, mData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull  ) {
    if(mData['state'] == 'Healthy'){
     
      $('td', nRow).eq(1).addClass('green');
    }

Comment: Awesome. But your code is based on old version of datatables, if you use the latest version, you can use my code instead. Please  mark my answer if it help you. Thanks.

Comment: Well now i am facing another issue. I am able to display the td color based on values. But when i am sorting on that column the color is fading away.

Comment: Not understand, can you update your new code above.